# Internet Accounts will not let me add my AOL account!

Tags: macos, mail.app, email, accounts

I went to my AOL Online account and changed my password because every time I try to add my AOL account to my iMac in Internet Accounts, a screen pops up for me that has my name, the email address box and a password box.  **But it won't take the new password.**

I just added to the actual *online* AOL site, so I can **not add**  AOL to the left box in Internet Accounts, therefore, I can **not** get my AOL Mail added to the Mailboxes in Mail.

Does anyone have a solution?  I'm not a computer genius...layman's terms please.

Comment: On my system when I click to add AOL it pops up a new sheet with nothing more than  "username, email or mobile." What version of macOS do you have? (Apple menu > About This Mac)

Comment: What do you mean "you added to the actual AOL site, so you can't add to the left box of Internet Accounts."  Can you clarify?  Can you also expand on "it won't take your password?"  Is there an error, is the box greyed out, etc?  If possible can you post a screen capture (`Shift-Cmd-3`) so we can see what you're seeing?